# ¿Cómo posicionar un texto a la derecha de una imagen?

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner un texto a la derecha en la parte superior de una imagen pero siempre se me coloca a la derecha por DEBAJO de la imagen, les dejo el código en `html` y, ¿quisiera saber si se puede hacer en `html` o en `css` ? porque tampoco puedo lograr nada en `css`.

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/"> (imagen en cuestion)
  <p>Lista de Lubricantes</p> <!-- esto es lo que quiero que vaya a la derecha -->
</div>
```

Comment: la ubicacion era dentro de la image o a un costado a la derecha?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Veo que casi todos te comentan el hecho de usar `float: left` y, sin embargo, nadie te explica el porque se produce este efecto.

Realmente esto se produce debido a que las etiquetas [`p tags`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/p.html) tienen por defecto la propiedad `display: block` y esto hace que actúen como bloques y que el texto se baje justo debajo de la imagen.

Sin embargo, puedes hacer que los elementos actúen como elementos `inline` (que se sitúen en la misma línea) pero teniendo las propiedades de los bloques (pueden tener altura, anchura...). Esto se consigue mediante la propiedad `display: inline-block`. De esta manera, el texto se situará a la derecha de la imagen ya que se posicionará en la misma línea que esta.

Por último, para poner el texto en la parte superior podrías usar la propiedad [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#propdef-vertical-align), propiedad que sólo actúa sobre elementos `inline` pero como hemos indicado que nuestro texto actúe como `inline-block` entonces nos va a permitir utilizarla. Mediante esta propiedad podemos determinar dónde va a estar alineado un elemento `inline` dentro de la línea en la que se encuentra. En este caso, como queremos que se sitúe en la parte superior, tendremos que usar el atributo `top`.

```css
#texto{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  <p id="texto">Lista de Lubricantes</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es que el texto aparezca a la derecha de la imagen, lo que tienes que hacer es flotar la imagen a la izquierda (con `float:left`):

```css
img { float:left; }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/"> (imagen en cuestion)
  <p>Lista de Lubricantes</p> <!-- esto es lo que quiero que vaya a la derecha -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrias quitar el `<p>` y ademas definir el `style="float:left;` en la imagen.

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" style="float:left;"> 
  <div>Lista de Lubricantes</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Esto hizo justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!

Comment: Nota: el atributo `align` es obsoleto y ha sido deprecado ([fuente](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html)). Seguramente funcionará, pero es mejor no usarlo y buscar una alternativa

Comment: Es verdad no me habia dado cuenta que el "align" era obsoleto, pero logras el mismo efecto usando style="float:left;", @AlvaroMontoro gracias por marcar el problema

Answer (score 2):

Este código te puede servir. Ubicas la imagen y el texto dentro de un contenedor en común y luego juegas con la posición del texto dentro de ese contenedor por medio de posiciones absolutas.

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg" />
  <p id="text">
    Texto superior-derecha!
  </p>
</div>
```