# Alinear contenido de 2 div verticalmente

Tags: html, css

Hola tengo 2 elementos div uno a lado del otro, en el primero se encuentra una imagen la propiedad de **height** en css con el valor de **auto** y en el segundo quiero que se encuentre un menú sencillo. Lo que quiero es que el menu quede en la parte de abajo y que coincida con la altura del primer div.

El código que tengo es este:

```css
   .mheader {
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
    }

    .logo {
     width:25%;
     background-color:#27AD57;
     float:left;
    }

    .logo_img {
     width:100%;
    }

    .menu {
     width:75%;
     float:right;
     vertical-align:bottom;
        text-align:bottom;
     background-color:#2600FF;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="mheader" >

     <div class="logo" >
         <img class="imagen" alt="imagen"/>
     </div>

     <div class="menu" >
      <span><a href="#" >Link A</a></span>
      <span><a href="#" >Link B</a></span>
      <span><a href="#" >Link C</a></span>
      <span><a href="#" >Link D</a></span>
     </div>

   </div>
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: Resultado 1]

Y lo que necesito es algo así

[image: Resultado bueno]

Comment: Mira si el enlace a mi respuesta en esta otra pregunta te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36074/16108

Comment: Prueba con un bottom: 0px en menu

Comment: Estupenda forma de hacer preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,

por partes; primero el contenedor principal, el **header**. Si te fijas, el *height* del header estará a 0px, esto es lo primero que vamos a arreglar. Para ello simplemente tenemos que añadir:
`overflow: auto;` a `.mheader`.

Ahora nuestro header tendrá el tamaño del contenido y podemos usarlo como referencia para posicionar el resto de elementos.

Next, que nuestro **menú** esté en el *bottom* del header. Primero añadimos:
`position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` a la clase `.menu`.
Esto hace que la posición del menú sea a *distancia 0px* del 'bottom'.
Para que el 'bottom' al que hacemos referencia no sea la página entera y sea el 'bottom' de nuestro header, le añadimos a
`.mheader` el atributo `position: relative;`.

Con esto ya tenemos el menú alineado al 'bottom' correcto, el de nuestro header.

Por último, como estamos usando posición absoluta en nuestro menú, este está solapando nuestra imagen. Esto se arregla fácilmente añadiendo
`display: inline-block;` al `.menu`.

Te dejo un jsfiddle con todo esto:

http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/8604/

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, gracias amigo esto me funciono bien, aunque también encontre y probé esto: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp y me gustaría saber cual de las dos formas es mas cómoda de usar

Comment: Buenas, la solución que comentas hace que tus `div` se comporten como tablas. Ese sería el único inconveniente que le veo. En mi caso ya he tenido problemas de estilos por culpa de las tablas en html, por eso optaría por evitarlas en la medida de lo posible. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que crees un tercer div y lo coloques encima de ese que tienes creado, después dale los valores de altura y anchura que mejor te vayan para lo que realmente quieres. Eso o dale una posición relativa y que el resto de elementos lo empujen hacia abajo.

De todos modos mira este link:
http://www.danielmayor.com/css-alineacion-abajo-como-posicionar-en-la-parte-baja

Un saludo.